# Не отправляется Ajax методом POST

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Есть 4 поля для регистрации.
При отправки ajax-запроса в обработчик php ничего не происходит, ничего не появляется.
Но если отправить запрос в этот же файл с ним самим и вывести через `var_dump` всю переменную POST, то значения полей там появляются.
В консоли никаких ошибок нет.

Вот JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   function load(){
      $("#RegZ").text("Загрузка");
   }
   function load_success(data){
      $("#alert").text(data);
   }
   $("#reg_s").click(function() {
      $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "ajax.php",
         dataType: "html",
         data: $("#register_ajax").serialize(),
         beforeSend: load,
         success: load_success
      });
   });
});
```

Вот форма:

```
<form name="regval" id="register_ajax" method="POST">
   <input name="username" type="text" id="reg_f" size="35" maxlength="70" placeholder=" Ф.И.О." required> 
   <input name="login" type="text" id="reg_f" maxlength=20 size="35" placeholder=" Логин" required>
   <input name="password" type="password" id="reg_f" maxlength=20 size="35" placeholder=" Пароль" required>
   <input name="r_password" type="password" id="reg_f" maxlength=20 size="35" placeholder=" Повторите пароль" required>
   <input type="submit" name="register" value="ЗАРЕГИСТРИРОВАТЬСЯ" id="reg_s"><br/> 
   <input type="submit" name="signup" value="ВОЙТИ" id="signup">
</form>
```

Comment: можно код формы? html

Comment: А это нормально, что load_success вызывается без аргументов, тогда как объявляется с ним?

Comment: @SLy_huh где вы видите его вызов?

Comment: @Mr.Proper а вы вообще в курсе, что делает браузер при нажатии на кнопку submit? :)

Comment: @PavelMayorov Отправляется запрос на сервер с данными полей ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так все работает, я немного изминил скрипт

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
function load(){
    $("#RegZ").text("Загрузка");
}
function load_success(data){
    $("#alert").text(data);
}
$("#register_ajax").submit(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "ajax.php",
         dataType: "html",
         data: $("#register_ajax").serialize(),
         beforeSend: load,
         success: load_success
        });
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое ! Заработало !